# What's the easiest way to change Playstation Network date of birth?

Tags: ps3, psn

I must have set up my account when I was 17 because my DOB is a year off.  I'd like to have it right in case I need to recover my password/account.  What's the easiest way?  I couldn't find it anywhere in the [PSN account settings online](http://playstation.com/psn/).

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to contact Playstation Support directly

Comment: So...when you were 17 you had a different birthday? :/

Comment: @Alex I hope you're being sarcastic :)

Comment: You said 'I must have set it up when I was 17 because my DOB is a year off'. That implies that when you were 17 your DOB was different to what it is now :P

Comment: @Alex Obviously, by "my DOB" I meant my PSN DOB haha :)

Comment: Oh, I see what he means.  He set it to 18 when he was 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. At least, not with your account settings. Sony uses your DOB when you want to retrieve your password, and a few other things.

You may try to contact Sony, or at least the PSN department, but I would be surprised if they did.

Comment: Sony actually can't, even if you contact them. I was on with support once (forgot my password and used a fake DOB). They reset my password and I asked if they could also change my DOB to my correct one and was told they can't do that.